# aggregations are not creating SSAS in MOLAP and ROLAP

Tags: performance, ssas, aggregation, partitioning, cube

1)According my understanding when we set storage setting as ROLAP for partition it creates a Indexed View. But I cant see it created in my DW.

2)What is the difference between Default and Unrestricted while defining aggregation

3) I designed my aggregation in MOLAP mode and selected one attribute called ProductName as Full.

```
Select [Measures].[Sales Amount] on Columns,
non empty [Dim Product].[Product Name].Members on Rows From [Sales OLTP]
```

i enabled "Get data from aggregation" in Sql server profiler. But unfortunately this event wont fires

Any help or is appreciated.